# scroll to a target which is inside a hidden container

Tags: javascript

Clicking a hash link (`<a href="#content">Go to content</a>`) jumps the document to the target container (`<div id="content">Content here</div>`). But when the target container is hidden (`display: none;)` it doesn't jump to it. I tried adding a click event listner to show the target container when the hash link is clicked, but still it doesn't jump to the target container.

How to fix that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

when `display: none;` is added in HTML, the page will be displayed as if the element is not there. You can use `visibility: hidden;` which will still occupy the same space. To reduce the height you can use the `height: 0;` attribute.

```
<div id="a">
</div>
<div id="b">
</div>
<a href="#a">Go to content</a>
<a href="#b">Go to content</a>


#b {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
   }
#a {
  background-color: red;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet sets up an event listener for all clicks on `<a>` elements in the body of the document. If the `href` of the clicked link starts with `#` we have a "local link" and this will trigger a removal of the `.hidden` class from the targeted element.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click",ev=>{
 const trg=ev.target;
 if(trg.tagName==="A"){
  const href=trg.getAttribute("href");
  if (href.match(/^#/))
   document.querySelector(href).classList.remove("hidden");
 }
})
```

```css
div { min-height: 300px; width: 90%; background-color: #eee; margin: 10px; padding: 10px}
div#content1 {background-color: #fdd;}
div#content2 {background-color: #dfd;}
.hidden {display:none}
```

```html
<a href="#content1">Go to content "one"</a><br>
<a href="#content2">Go to content "two"</a>
<div>The above link jumps within the document to the target container.</div><div id="content1" class="hidden">Content "one" here.</div>
<div>Another div to fill the page</div>
<div>One more div ...</div><div id="content2" class="hidden">Content "two" here.</div>
<div>... and her the final one.</div>
```